# How to check security vulnerabilities of android app

Tags: javascript, java, android

Recently I have developed an android application, but before implementation of the application I like to check for any security vulnerabilities. So guys is there any tool to check the security vulnerabilities of an android application

Comment: I don't know of any tools per se, but general things to check include making sure user data is stored securely, and if your app talks to an API, then make sure that a malicious user can't hack your app and try to do damage.

Comment: You can try https://github.com/linkedin/qark